# Sum If Not Strike Through Refresh/Recalculate

Tags: refresh, strikethrough

I found this script that I would like to utilize.  It does calculations that does not include strike through value.  However, it does not refresh/recalculate with edits.  I have to manually refresh in order to recalculate.  The script is below.

```
   function SumIfNotStrikeThrough(rangeA1Notation) 
{
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet(); 
  var mysheet = ss.getActiveSheet();

  var dataRange = mysheet.getDataRange();
  var mydatarange = mysheet.getRange(rangeA1Notation);
  var numRows = mydatarange.getLastRow();
  var rowindex = mydatarange.getRowIndex();
  var columnindex = mydatarange.getColumnIndex();

  var total =0;

  for(i=rowindex;i<=numRows;i++)
  {
    if(dataRange.offset(i-1, columnindex-1, 1, 1).isBlank() != true && dataRange.offset(i-1, columnindex-1, 1, 1).getFontLine() != "line-through")
    {
      var temp = dataRange.offset(i-1, columnindex-1, 1, 1).getValue();
      total = total + temp;
    }    
  }

  return total;
}
```

Comment: You would like to utilize this where and what is it you want to refresh?  People on this site can help with many applications, but you have to be more specific.

Comment: I am using it at work to sum travel budget spreadsheet.  when travel has been cancelled, it is striked through with notes added.  they do this for history instead of deleting/zero it out.